# Borrar Registro LINQ to ENTITY

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Intento borrar un registro de esta forma:

```
 var cSelect = from x in contexto.BloqueoExcursion
                      where x.BLE_BloqueoID == BloqueoID
                      select x;




        foreach (var item in cSelect)
        {
            var eSelect = new BloqueoExcursion { BloqueoExcursionId = item.BloqueoExcursionId, BLE_BloqueoID = item.BLE_BloqueoID, BLE_ExcursionId = item.BLE_ExcursionId, BLE_PrecioExc = item.BLE_PrecioExc };
           contexto.Entry(eSelect).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;

        }
```

Luego he intentado así:

```
contexto.ChangeObjectState(eSelect, System.Data.EntityState.Deleted);
```

Y también así:

```
contexto.BloqueoExcursion.Remove(eSelect);
```

Las dos primeras opciones me dan el siguiente error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Error al adjuntar una entidad de tipo 'Gerente_Mayorista.Models.BloqueoExcursion' porque otra entidad del mismo tipo ya tiene el mismo valor de clave principal. Esto puede ocurrir cuando se usa el método 'Attach' o cuando se establece el estado de una entidad en 'Unchanged' o 'Modified' si algunas entidades del gráfico tienen valores de clave en conflicto. Puede deberse a que algunas entidades son nuevas y no han recibido todavía los valores de clave generados por la base de datos. En este caso, use el método 'Add' o el estado de entidad 'Added' para hacer un seguimiento del gráfico y establezca después el estado de las entidades que no son nuevas como 'Unchanged' o 'Modified', según corresponda.'

Si uso esta instrucción:

```
contexto.BloqueoExcursion.Remove(eSelect);
```

Me dice esto:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'El objeto no se puede eliminar porque se encontró en el ObjectStateManager.'

RECALCO QUE:

1. No uso entidades relacionadas.
2. No tengo relaciones en las tablas.
3. El Linq si trae datos (2 registros).

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
var cSelect = from x in contexto.BloqueoExcursion
                  where x.BLE_BloqueoID == BloqueoID
                  select x;

contexto.BloqueoExcursion.RemoveRange(cSelect);
contexto.SaveChanges();
```

O mejor aún:

```
contexto.BloqueoExcursion.RemoveRange(contexto.BloqueoExcursion.Where(x => x.BLE_BloqueoID == BloqueoID));
contexto.SaveChanges();
```

En el caso de `contexto.BloqueoExcursion.Remove(eSelect);` el error se debe a que tratas de borrar una entidad que no está en el `DbSet` porque la acabas de instanciar. Debes referirte a las mismas entidades que sacaste del contexto.

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó con RemoveRange y con la segunda opción que me diste.
¿Funcionará independientemente de la cantidad de registros que se encuentre con el Where?
Saludos.
Eduardo.

Comment: Si, lo que hace `RemoveRange()` es marcar como eliminado a cada uno de los elementos del `IEnumerable<T>` donde T es BloqueoExcursion (o como se llame la entidad) para que luego se eliminen cuando se llame a `SaveChanges()`.